# CSS / jQuery: Placing items at window height causing layout issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I am using jQuery to position a few elements relative to the size of the window.  While this works perfectly if the window is full size, if I have the debugger open or a shorter window, the resulting layout is incorrect.

Q: Is there anyway to place things relative to the maximum possible window height, rather than the current window height?

### jQuery

```
var navbarHeight = parseInt($(".navbar").css("height"));

$("#home-part-1").css("height", $(window).innerHeight() - navbarHeight);
$("#home-part-2").css("height", $(window).innerHeight());
$("#home-part-3").css("height", $(window).innerHeight());

$("#divider-1").css("top", $(window).innerHeight() - navbarHeight);
$("#divider-2").css("top", (2 * $(window).innerHeight()) - navbarHeight);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `vh` units, i.e. `height: 100vh`? I'm not sure if it will take those other things into account or not, though.

Comment: Have you tried `screen.width`?

Comment: I've tried both, and both only consider the viewable portion of the screen.  window.outerHeight doesnt care if the debugger is open, but its pretty difficult to use because you need to know the height of taskbars and bookmark bars in order to position things accurately

Comment: Why are you using JS to position elements? What are you trying to do that you can't do in CSS? Also, define "maximum possible height" as a user can make a window infinetly large.

Comment: I am attempting to create a website where the home page has a few concepts to cover, and I want each concept to use 1 full window to contain the information for 1 topic.  On the side of the screen I give the user the ability to jump through the concepts, almost like slides.  And by "maximum possible" I mean the size of the screen should the user have nothing else open, and their screen maximized

Comment: When I refresh the page with a less-than-maximized screen, the objects appear in the wrong place because the returned height is based on what is currently viewable.. does that make sense?

Comment: Played around with it, looks like this returns the maximum viewable screen size *almost* correctly : `screen.height-window.outerHeight+window.innerHeight`. Caveat is that the tabs change in size slightly, so there's still a small difference between checking it on a large or small browser size.

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice to try to lay out your page this way. There is not a lot I can do to help with the solution you are specifying. Its not going to work that way. Take a look at this though: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage . That might help you.

Comment: This is exactly what I mean, but I guess I worry how the screen changes upon opening devtools or changing the width.  I would like the know the total potentially-viewable screen size should the user have their screen maximized

Comment: there is no maximum size. imagine the user has their computer plugged into a 110 inch TV. The best you can do is use bootstrap3 to make your website responsive. Use a responsive layout with the widths set using the 12 columns and that will take care of the width. Using the plugin should help with height issues. Are you familiar with bootstrap?

Comment: yes, I'm currently using it.  I understand what you mean about the indefinite maximum, but the dimension I am looking for is the height of the window should the user maximize their browser